# Jedi-VIM: Popup appears just in some cases

Tags: python, vim, python-mode, jedi-vim

I installed several plugins to create a kind of python-IDE with vim 7.3 on Mac (Yosemite).

See my .vimrc for a list of plugins - settings:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
filetype plugin indent on
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
Bundle 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required

syntax enable
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
let g:solarized_visibility = "high"
let g:solarized_contrast = "high"
colorscheme solarized
" Python-mode
" Activate rope
" Keys:
" K             Show python docs
" <Ctrl-Space>  Rope autocomplete
" <Ctrl-c>g     Rope goto definition
" <Ctrl-c>d     Rope show documentation
" <Ctrl-c>f     Rope find occurrences
" <Leader>b     Set, unset breakpoint (g:pymode_breakpoint enabled)
" [[            Jump on previous class or function (normal, visual, operator modes)
" ]]            Jump on next class or function (normal, visual, operator modes)
" [M            Jump on previous class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)
" ]M            Jump on next class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)

let g:pymode_rope = 0

" Documentation
let g:pymode_doc = 1
let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'

"Linting
let g:pymode_lint = 1
let g:pymode_lint_checker = 'pyflakes,pep8'
" Auto check on save
let g:pymode_lint_on_write = 1

" Support virtualenv
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1

" Enable breakpoints plugin
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_bind = '<leader>b'

" syntax highlighting
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all

let g:pymode_options_max_line_length = 79
let g:pymode_options_colorcolumn = 1
let g:pymode_python = 'python'
let g:pymode_indent = 1
" Don't autofold code
let g:pymode_folding = 0


" NerdTree
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Powerline setup
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2
```

This is the vim-version-information

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov  6 2014 14:32:04)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

If I work in a python-file, I expected a "popup-window" for autocompletion every time I press Ctrl-Space or period - but this is not the case

Example
No Popup:

[image]

Here is a popup

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Its really unclear what you have done, what extensions you have used and what exactly what you are asking. You are going to have to give more information as to what you have done and what exactly you want to happen and what the fault is.

Comment: Sorry for this - I added several information.